# How to check a checkbox from bean in JavaServerFaces?

Tags: jsf

My requirement is that i am getting some sort of values from database and i have a page which consists ofcolumns of multiselect checkboxes related to each other, I want to make the checkboxes with values which are retreived from the Database to  be checked before rendering the page

Comment: Can you post the code of what you have tried so far?

Comment: I don't have code..For Boolean checkbox we can do like what samuelgrigolato answered...But for me its a multiselect checkbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to add a Map attribute to your backing bean, and point the checkboxes to this map:

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{backingBean.checkedValues[dynamicOption.keyAttribute]}" />
```

PS: KeyClass is meant to be replaced to the actual key class you have on your dynamic entity.

EDIT: solution using h:selectManyCheckbox

```
<h:selectManyCheckbox value="#{backingBean.collectionOfKeyClassValues}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{backingBean.dynamicallyPopulatedOptions}" itemLabel="descriptionProperty" itemValue="keyPropertyMusBeKeyClass"> 
</h:selectManyCheckbox>
```

Comment: Looks like OP's using `<h:selectManyCheckbox>`

Comment: And it is a multiselect checkbox...so how to apply map attribute for that

Comment: Can you please read my latest edit inside the answer? Does that helps you solve your problem? Sorry if I'm yet misunderstanding the problem. =)

Comment: whether collectionOfKeyClassValues and dynamicallyPopulatedOptions are list

Comment: Your action method can dynamically populate these two lists with database values. "f:selectItems" work with a list.

Comment: And after the rendering of page if user selects more checkboxes whether we will be able to get those additional selected values in bean.how

Comment: Hi samuelgrigolato.What you told is actually working..Thanks.I am using string array to store the values.What if user selects some checkboxes again and submit the form.In getlist(collectionOfKeyClassValues} i have hardcoded some values of string array.So how will we get the newly selected values after user submits the form..whether the hardcoded thing in setlist() inside will override the dynamic selected list from user when we use getlist() method.Hope you get my question

Comment: The "collectionOfKeyClassValues" property accessors should not have any logic to fetch the data. They need to be backed by an attribute on the backing bean, otherwise JSF wouldn't be able to "set" the newly selected values on your bean. Whenever the user first access the page, the respective action should set the "pre-selected" values using the "setCollectionOfKeyClassValues", this way when the user submits the form, JSF will "set" the selected values in the same list and correctly re-render the component with the new selections.

Comment: Sorry hardcoded in getlist()

Comment: ok i got it.If the user submits the form whether the page load will set the checkboxes to default checked instead of modified  since i want action to be on page load initially for setting default checkboxes